# Self join in doctrine-orm: Symfony

Tags: symfony, join, doctrine-orm

I have an entity for logs where I save application error records with a field for inserted timestamp.
My requirement is to purge entries which are older than 10 days from last log record.
My entity structure is like:

```
class MyacuvueLogs
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id()
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue()
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
     */
    private $mobile;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer", nullable=true)
     */
    private $created;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $apiName;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
     */
    private $apiReqParams;
}
```

Please help.

My code to delete old log records is as below:

```
public function getOldLog($max_time)
    {
        $remove_rows = $this->createQueryBuilder('p')
                            ->delete()
                            ->where('p.created < :createdBeforeLimitDate')
                            ->setParameter('createdBeforeLimitDate',$max_time-10*86400);
        return "deleted rows";
    }
```

However this is not working.

Comment: 10 days from last log record? do you mean 10 days from today?

Comment: No, I mean 10 days from last recorded log. So if last row has created value is 1560757741 then I need to delete records with created less than (1560757741-10*86400)

Comment: use a cronjob then

Comment: two-step process: 1. find the max timestamp, 2. delete according to your formula. I would put this in a command or (api) route and trigger it via cronjob.

Comment: Hi @Jakumi Thanks for your suggestion. I am doing it through command only. But in the repository function I am not able to fire it using a single query.

Comment: yeah ... you can't at the same time use the table you're updating in a subquery. that's why I said it's a two step process ... and not one.

Comment: Hi @Jakumi! I have added my code from repository file (to be called from command) to delete rows but it's not working. I am able to get max timestamp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have the following code:

```
public function getOldLog($max_time)
{
    $remove_rows = $this->createQueryBuilder('p')
                        ->delete()
                        ->where('p.created < :createdBeforeLimitDate')
                        ->setParameter('createdBeforeLimitDate',$max_time-10*86400);
    return "deleted rows";
}
```

that code doesn't execute anything, because you just built a query and stored it in a variable. and then: nothing.

you have to call `getQuery` and `getResult` for it to be executed:

```
public function getOldLog($max_time)
{
    $remove_rows = $this->createQueryBuilder('p')
                        ->delete()
                        ->where('p.created < :createdBeforeLimitDate')
                        ->setParameter('createdBeforeLimitDate', $max_time-10*86400)
                        ->getQuery()     // <- new
                        ->getResult();   // <- new
    return "deleted rows";
}
```